# Error while generating webservice

Tags: web-services, tomcat, axis

I tried a tutorial webservice, just a helloworld sort of program and tried to generate webservice using tomcat and eclipse. This is the error I see

Any pointer/help is appreciated

> IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
>     axis-admin failed with  {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP (502)Proxy Error ( The Uniform Resource Locator (URL) does not use a recognized protocol. Either the protocol is not supported or the request was not typed correctly. Confirm that a valid protocol is in use (for example, HTTP for a Web request).  )

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this problem.  I am getting it as well and the pickings on google look pretty slim

Comment: Nope I did not get an answer :(

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you choose `Axis` instead of **`Axis2`** while you're creating web service.

In `"Web Service" screen` (when you press create web service option that screen comes).

> There are 3 links under configuration. "Web Service Runtime..." link has option about Axis runtime.

It must be consistent with your **installed** `axis`.